# flutter failed upload app bundle to play store

Tags: flutter, build, bundle

I create mobile app by Flutter ,and as figured in flutter documentation I create key an make bundle to upload it ,but I get this error :

`you downloaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. APK file or Android App Bundle must be signed in release mode. Learn more about signing files or packages`

### How can I change the build from debug to release mode

Comment: Refer to this https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Comment: @dm_tr as I mentioned i did that as shown in that link

Answer (score 1):

First time i also faced this issue.

You can follow https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android to build app bundle.

You should pay attention at this stage,

/android/app/build.gradle file:

```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
           // Signing with the debug keys for now,
           // so `flutter run --release` works.
           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       }
   }
```

You have to change this code block with:

```
   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

This all things are mentioned in mentioned  [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)

At first i thought these code blocks are same that's why i pointed out that code block.

Comment: I did same but not solved ,I tried by android studio and upload succeded

Answer (score 0):

use this at terminal;

```
   flutter build appbundle
```

Comment: I used this too same

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can't upload a debug apk file on Play Store since it is a production release. So you need to make a release or signed apk or aab file and then upload it .

For more details on how to make it use https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Comment: I run flutter build apk --release but same

Comment: Lean to read a question entirely before providing an answer